"nvidia-smi" doesn't work in a proxmox VM
Morning everyone,
I just face some huge problems during the last days.
I usally boot ubuntu server 24.04 in a Proxmox VM with my nvidia graphic card. It was working perfectly. But now when I try to "nidia-smi" in my temrinal, i get "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."
What should I do ?
Any ideas ?

You may have the xorg open-source driver, xorg open-source drivers cannot communicate with nvidia-smi, install proprietary drivers from from this menu:

P.S: It's better to keep with open-source ones but to make nvidia-smi work proprietary ones must be used.
